# Elasticsearch the best way to design multiple one to many and many to many

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two scenarios that I want to support but I don’t know the best way to design relations in the elasticsearch. I read the entire elasticsearch documentation but I couldn’t find the best way to design types for my scenarios.

1. Multiple one to many.
   Let’s assume that I have the following tables in my relational database that I want to transfer to the elasticsearch:

> Transaction table
>  Id
>  User1Id
>  User2Id
>  ….
>
> User table
>  Id
>  Name

Transaction contains two references to User. As far as I know I cannot use the parent->child relation specifying two parents? I need to store transaction and user in separate types because they can be changed separately. I need to be able to search transaction through user details and return users connected with transactions. Any idea how to design such structure in the elastic search?

2. Many to many
   Let’s assume that we have the following tables:

> Order
>  Id
>  …
>
> OrderLine 
> OrderId
>  UserId
>  Amount
>  …
>
> User 
> Id
>  Name

Order line is always saved with the order so I thought that I can store order with order lines as a nested object relation but the user must be in the separate table. Is there any way how can I connected multiple users from order line with user type? I assume that I can use application side join but I need to retrieve order and order line always together and be able to search order by user data.
I can use grandparent and grandchildren relations but then I need to make joins in the application. Any idea how to design it in the best way?

Comment: If you have real data, do some tests with it using real queries. Evaluate the performance and choose the best one. There's no black and white here and the best option depends on the specifics of the use case (data, mappings, queries). You can go with parent/child, denormalized data or application joins. It all depends on the specifics: the application joins can save you or they can be awful, you can have not much data and parent/child can be ideal, or the trade off of the multiple updates can be ok with denormalized data. The best is to test and choose afterwards.

Comment: @AndreiStefan is right. ES responds faster as you denormalise your data. Yes, Parent-Child and other such joins are a possibility, but they do not guarantee performance. If you are looking for heavy querying on a large data set, a logical compromise would be to do joins beforehand at the application level and indexing the denormalised data so as to keep your queries as light as possible.

Comment: Thanks guys I spend some times for testing and I found out that there is no one way to design types in ES but I need to design types for specific business requirements.